# Find unordered cycle

Tags: probability, graph-theory, random-graphs

In an undirected random graph of 11 vertices the probability of an edge being present between a pair of vertices is 2/5. What is the expected number of unordered cycle of length 3.
I think the answer should be

$${11\choose 3} \cdot\left(\frac 25\right)^3=10.56\approx 10.$$

But the options available are 22, 33, 44, 55. please help me

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please consider using Mathjax in your questions to make it easier to understand, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is correct. There are $\binom{11}3$ potential unordered cycles, and each of them exists with probability $\left(\frac25\right)^3$. These probabilities aren't independent, but they don't have to be in order to apply the linearity of expectation. There must be either an error in the text or a misunderstanding of the problem statement.

Comment: I am sure that the questions as well as the options are correct.

Comment: @user585445 Then it must be the case that you have misstated the problem. Where did the problem come from?